# Get e-mail addresses of failed subscriptions for SSRS data driven subscription

Tags: ssrs, monitoring

We are using SSRS Enterprise and have implemented data driven subscriptions.

We have implemented a monitoring solution to inform us of failed sends.

However, even after increasing verbosity to the max and enabling remote errors on SSRS there is no info as to which actual recipient the subscription failed for.

This is obviously super worrying as it could be an important decision maker that is not receiving their report.

The only error message I can find is : "Terminé : 105 traité(s) sur un total de 105 ; 6 erreurs."

(the server is in French but it means 105 processed with 6 errors. We need to know who those errors concern)